# Is it possible to have different vertex colors for every `InstancedBufferGeometry` instance?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was wondering if it is possible to have different vertex colors for every `InstancedBufferGeometry` instance.

```
const xRes = 3;
const yRes = 2;
const numVertices = xRes * yRes;
geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
geometry.copy(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(3, 2, xRes, yRes));

const particleCount = 500;

const vertexColorArray = new Float32Array(particleCount * numVertices * 3);
for (let i = 0; i < particleCount * numVertices * 3; i++) {
    vertexColorArray[i] = Math.random();
}
const colors = new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertexColorArray, 3);
geometry.addAttribute("vertexColor", colors);
```

in this case all instances share the same vertex colors, and when I do `const colors = new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(vertexColorArray, 3, 1);` each instance has a separate color, but not per vertex.

shaders look like this:

```
<script id="vshader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    precision highp float;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
    uniform float time;

    attribute vec3 position;
    attribute vec3 translate;
    attribute vec3 vertexColor;

    varying vec3 vVertexColor;

    void main() {
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(translate, 1.0);
        vec3 trTime = vec3(
            translate.x + time,
            translate.y + time, 
            translate.z + time
        );
        float scale = 1.0;
        scale = scale * 10.0 + 10.0;
        mvPosition.xyz += position * scale;
        vVertexColor = vertexColor;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision highp float;
    varying vec3 vVertexColor;

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vVertexColor, 1);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know if, when using `InstancedBufferGeoemtry`, it is possible to have each vertex of each instance have a different vertex color.

Yes, it is possible.

One way is to compute the color in the shader programmatically, or via a look-up table based on the geometry vertex ID and the instance ID:

```
geometry.addAttribute( 'vertexID', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertexIDs, 1 ) );

geometry.addAttribute( 'instanceID', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( instanceIDs, 1 ) );
```

So, in your shader, you have access to the vertex ID of the original geometry, and you also have access to the ID of the instance. From those two values, you can set the color in the shader uniquely for each vertex of each instance.

three.js r.84

Comment: ok, looking up values by index and vertex ids makes sense. — I'm still not entirely sure how to actually implement this though:
so `vertexIds` and `instanceIds` would be `Uint16Array`s, since I want to use them as index for an array of color values (which would be passed in as `uniform vec3`?). however, `int`s don't seem to be allowed as `attribute`s, and with `uniform vec3` I'd have to specify the size of the array beforehand, right?

Comment: (1) You can pack the vertex color data in a texture. (2) Read https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core.BufferAttributes/BufferAttribute_Types.

Comment: ended up generating sort of a sprite texture, using the instance id to calculate the right uv coordinates offset.

Comment: @WestLangley how to set the color in the shader uniquely for each vertex of each instance? any further informations?